# Java Deck of Cards List Shuffle

Tags: java, arraylist, shuffle

Need some assistance on this program I'm working on. Basically a card draw program that creates a deck of cards (card and deck classes), shuffles the created deck, and adds the first card of the shuffled deck to the player's hand. (CardPlayer class).

```
package cards;

public class Card {
        private String[]cardSuit = {"Hearts", "Diamonds", "Spades", "Clubs"};
        private String[]cardFaceValue = {"Ace", "King", "Queen", "Jack", "10", "9", "8", "7", "6", "5", "4", "3", "2"};
        
        private int suit;
        private int faceValue;
        
        public Card(int newSuit, int newValue) {
            suit = newSuit;
            faceValue = newValue;
        }
        
        public String toString() {
            String card = cardFaceValue[faceValue] + " of " + cardSuit[suit];
            
            return card;
        }
    }
```

```
package cards;

import java.util.*;

public class Deck {
        
        ArrayList<Card> deck = new ArrayList<>();
        
        public Deck() {
            for(int suit = 0; suit <= 3; suit++) {
                for(int value = 0; value <= 12; value++) {
                    deck.add(new Card(suit,value));
                }
            }
        }
        public void Shuffle() {
            Collections.shuffle(deck);
        }
        public Card Deal() {
            Card card = deck.get(0);
            deck.remove(0);
            return card;
        }
    }
```

```
package cards;

import java.util.*;

public class CardPlayer {

        Deck deck = new Deck();
        
        ArrayList<Card> hand = new ArrayList<>();

        public void getCard(){
            hand.add(deck.Deal());
        }

        public ArrayList<Card> showCards(){
            
            return hand;
        }

    }
```

```
package cards;

public class Demonstration {
        
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Deck deck;
        deck = new Deck();
        
        CardPlayer cardPlayer;
        cardPlayer = new CardPlayer();
        
        System.out.println("The deck contains the cards: " + deck.deck);
        
        deck.Shuffle();
        System.out.println("New order of cards: " + deck.deck);
        
        cardPlayer.getCard();
        cardPlayer.getCard();
        cardPlayer.getCard();
        cardPlayer.getCard();
        cardPlayer.getCard();
        System.out.println("The card player's hand is now: " + cardPlayer.showCards());
        
    }
}
```

My issue is that whenever I run the demonstration program, the deck and shuffle work, but when I try to show the cards in the player's hand, it's always the same cards in the order created by the initial deck creation, without the shuffle. How would I go about fixing this issue?

Comment: I would like to add that you aren't following Java naming conventions for methods (in some places). Method names should be camelCased i.e., they should start with a lower case letter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are having two instances of `Deck` class - one in the main method and one in the `CardPlayer` class. The one in the `CardPlayer` class is used in `getCard` but that deck isn't shuffled.

Either shuffle the deck created in `CardPlayer` class. Or pass the shuffled deck created in main to the constructor of the `CardPlayer` class.